# Cloud Logging Advanced Log Filters: Find HTTP Requests >= Duration

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

Google's Advanced Cloud Logging Filters seem incredibly powerful, but equally complex to use. How does one craft a logging query that finds all HTTP requests with a duration longer than 3 seconds, which also contains the text `foo bar`?

I've read through the [documentation, but it leaves a bit to be desired](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters) (it seems directed towards language authors, not users of the system). I know [there is a field for Duration](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters#values_and_conversions), but does anyone have an example on how to use it?

**Update 4/2022**: The documentation has gotten a lot better since writing this, [take a look](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To filter logs by duration and text ("foo bar") for the default App Engine instance, you can run the following under advanced filter:

```
metadata.serviceName="appengine.googleapis.com"
metadata.labels."appengine.googleapis.com/module_id"="default"
log="appengine.googleapis.com/request_log"
protoPayload.latency > 3s
"foo bar"
```

Comment: I did't see any docs for latency filter under advanced search.  However, you can Ctrl-Space to see list of available fields for creating a filter.

Comment: Latency is one of the few metrics in Cloud Logging that requires a unit (s in this example, but other SI time units also work)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean latency? Something like this should works

```
protoPayload.latency > 3s
```